# React Google Recaptcha "executeRecaptcha" function is undefined problem

Tags: reactjs, recaptcha

When loginBefore function is invoked by another component I need to assign the returned captcha token to captchaToken variable but executeRecaptcha is always undefined, so it executes the code block in if statement. Somehow I need to wait until executeRecaptcha function is initialized and then call function of getCaptchaToken I think. Is there any good way to do this? Thanks for the helps.

```
import { useGoogleReCaptcha } from 'react-google-recaptcha-v3';
export const useAxiosClient = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { executeRecaptcha } = useGoogleReCaptcha();

  const getCaptchaToken = async (action: string) => {
    if (!executeRecaptcha) {
      console.log('Execute recaptcha not yet available');
      return;
    }
    return await executeRecaptcha(action);
  };

  const loginBefore = async () => {
    const captchaToken = await getCaptchaToken('login');
```

I tried to invoke getCaptchaToken function after a certain amount of delay and that worked but that won't always work and not a good solution I think.

Answer (score 0):

I used `react-google-recaptcha-v3` and that behaviour was very confusing to me.
There is a new library that implements invisible reCAPTCHA for [react](https://react.dev) called [@rusted/react-recaptcha-v3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rusted/react-recaptcha-v3)

It has built-in action queue system that cares about that.
Just use as following.

```js
import {
    useExecuteReCaptcha,
    useSkipInjectionDelay,
} from '@rusted/react-recaptcha-v3'
export const useAxiosClient = () => {

  const executeRecaptcha  = useExecuteReCaptcha();

  const loginBefore = async () => {
    const captchaToken = await getCaptchaToken('login');
    //other desired stuff
  }
}
```

**`executeRecaptcha` function is always available**. Promise with Google Recaptcha token will be resolved as soon and reCAPTCHA script loaded.

Please note! **Wrap your parent components with `ReCaptchaProvider`** otherwise promises will be rejected immediately.

You can check [GitHub repository for this package](https://github.com/RustedLabs/react-google-recaptcha-v3) it has much cleaner source code with rich tests implemented.

Also, take a look at `injectionDelay` provider property + `useSkipInjectionDelay` hook in case you want to now blow up [PageSpeed score](https://pagespeed.web.dev) of your website.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is coming here from Google, I solved this by moving my Recaptcha higher order component **higher up in the hierarchy**. My guess is that this component should never be rerendered.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error. And When I log executeRecaptcha this shows me.
`ƒ (e){if(!C||!C.execute)throw new Error("<GoogleReCaptchaProvider /> Google Recaptcha has not been loaded");return C.execute(x.current,{action:e})}`
I used this trick and I think the problem is gone:

```
const handleRecaptcha = useCallback(async () => { 
 if (!executeRecaptcha) {
      console.log("Execute recaptcha not yet available");
      return;
    }
try {
      const token = await executeRecaptcha("homepage");
      console.log("token", token);
      if (token) {
//do sth
    }
} catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      setTimeout(() => handleRecaptcha(), 100);
    }
},[executeRecaptcha]);
```